# What does ct stand for in drugs?

Tags: medical

What does "ct" stand for in the following product advertised by Wallmart:

"Buy:ANY ONE (1) Dulcolax® Tablets 25ct+, Dulcolax® Suppositories 4ct+, Dulcolax Pink"

http://wm6.walmart.com/MediaOMP/2014/BoehringerIngelheim/01_BOE_67418_DulcolaxBate/images/Dulcolax_2015_Walmart_rebate_form.pdf

Comment: "Count" -- the number of individual items in the package.

Comment: Also "ct+" is here.  So "25ct+" means this offer applies to a package of 25 or more tablets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stands for *count*, and in this context means the number of tablets, number of suppositories, etc.

This is a common abbreviation for labelling quantities of products for sale.

> Count (ct), a frequently used abbreviation for a quantity of an object

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CT
(See *Time and units of measure* section.)

Some additional examples of ct meaning the number of product units in a package/container:

[http://www.amazon.com/Crayola-8ct-Washable-Markers-Fine/dp/B00006IFJ3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006IFJ3)

http://www.missionmenus.com/en/products/view/mission-flour-burrito-8ct

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had looked up Wikipedia but there were so many definitions for ct that I somehow missed that one.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure, but I think that in this context, *ct* stands for *coated tablet*.

From [The Free Dictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/coated+tablet):

> a solid disc of one or more pharmaceutic agents that is (1) coated with sugar or a flavoring to mask the taste or (2) enteric-coated, meaning that it is coated with a substance that resists dissolution in the stomach but allows release of the medication in the intestine.

Comment: This can't be correct in context because the suppository product is labelled *4 ct.*

Comment: @JimReynolds Why should a suppository not come in coated form, at least technically/ theoretically?

Comment: Well, good question. My highest confidence is actually knowing that *x*ct on a product label or container has a standard meaning in commerce and accounting. Also, a suppository would not be called a tablet.